# How to scan records with a given field set to null

Tags: go, amazon-dynamodb

I need to select all the records whose field `token` in `null`. Is the the `ScanInput` here below correct?

```
type AuthEntry struct {
    UserID    string    `dynamodbav:"userId"`
    Token     string    `dynamodbav,nullempty:"token"`
    CreatedOn time.Time `dynamodbav:"createdOn"`
}

...

t := time.Now().Add(time.Duration(-300000) * time.Millisecond).UTC()
params := &dynamodb.ScanInput{
    TableName:            aws.String(tableName),
    ProjectionExpression: aws.String("userId"),
    ExpressionAttributeValues: map[string]types.AttributeValue{
        "t": &types.AttributeValueMemberS{*aws.String(t.String())},
        "null": &types.AttributeValueMemberNULL{true},
    },
    FilterExpression: aws.String("createdOn < :t and (attribute_not_exists(token) or token = :null)"),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as explained [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=218119) it is correct.